# Is a macro the best solution?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, search

Im looking to have excel display all totes that have an expiration date less than or equal to todays date. It seems using a function is not an efficient option...so would using VBA be a better option, and if so, how? Im very new to VBA but am trying to learn as I go, so any help is a blessing.
[EXCEL SNIP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iohv.png)

Updated the SNIP img of the worksheet...much simpler.

Comment: Rather than posting an answer you can [edit] your question. It might be helpful for you to take the [tour] to see how things work here.

Comment: Are you able to add a helper column? From your screenshot, column C could be a formula along the lines of `=B2<Today()` (copied down to all the cells) that returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE` and you could filter on that.

Comment: Thanks Mokubai, I will indeed!

Comment: EngineerToast - The list is insanely long and I didnt want to have to scroll through all the entries. My goal was to have a command box that I enter the date and it returns all tote #'s that have exp dates equal or less than. I am not knowledgeable with VBA but I am trying to learn.

Comment: @MVUser,, which column is tote , I guess is A,, and u mean to say that you need data from column A has date in Col B is either less than or equals to Today's Date ? This can be attain by Excel worksheet function , combination of INDEX & MATCH dynamically (based on Date in cell) ,,, as well as VBA macro can do this also,,, please confirm !

Comment: @MVUser,, or you want to get the SUM of Column A which has match date less than or equals to today ? I guess totes is TOTAL !!

Comment: Not looking for the SUM, just the individual tote numbers entered into column A...and only those with a date prior to or including the present date. I will look into the INDEX and MATCH route, thank you so much Rajesh S!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but what about just using a Filter? Which you could do directly on the worksheet or using VBA.

Comment: Ron, youre not mistaken at all, that works perfectly, lol! I overlooked the obvious...Thank you Ron!